# Failure to install `mclust` package in R in Windows 10

Tags: r, installation, package

When I want to install the package `mclust`, I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("mclust")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp1/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
       binary source needs_compilation
mclust  5.2.3    5.3              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘mclust’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mclust_5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2792962 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'mclust' ...
** package 'mclust' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran -m32     -O3  -mtune=core2 -c mclust.f -o mclust.o
make: gfortran: Command not found
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:206: recipe for target 'mclust.o' failed
make: *** [mclust.o] Error 127
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="mclust.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' OBJECTS="init.o mclust.o mclustaddson.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mclust'
* removing 'C:/Users/hp1/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/mclust'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\hp1\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\hp1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiAzB7h/downloaded_packages/mclust_5.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\hp1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiAzB7h\downloaded_packages’
```

When digging for solutions on how to fix it, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590077/installing-mclust-r-package) where the OP says in a comment that the issue was arising due to missing `llpack` and `lblas` libraries, which they fixed by installing `lapackdev` and `blasdev` packages. But when I try to install these packages, I get error. I checked all my 12 repositories and tried again, but same result.

```
> install.packages("lapackdev")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp1/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lapackdev’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
> setRepositories(graphics = getOption("menu.graphics"),
+                 ind = NULL, addURLs = character())
--- Please select repositories for use in this session ---


 1: + CRAN                   2:   BioC software       
 3:   BioC annotation        4:   BioC experiment     
 5:   BioC extra             6: + CRAN (extras)       
 7:   Omegahat               8:   R-Forge             
 9:   rforge.net            10:   CRAN (extras, https)
11:   R-Forge [https]       12:   rforge.net [https]  

Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces, or an empty line to cancel
1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
> install.packages("lapackdev")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp1/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lapackdev’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
```

Same with `blasdev`:

```
> install.packages("blasdev")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp1/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘blasdev’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
```

What is going on and how do I get `mclust` to install?

Comment: Try this: https://sites.google.com/site/jivsoft/Home/r-blas-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as the following solved the issue (i.e., `mclust` was installed successfully) without needing to install the 2 packages I mention in the question. So, this might help someone facing difficulty install `mclust`.

I updated R version from 3.25 to 3.4, and R studio version from 0.9 to the latest (1.0.143 at the time of writing this answer), and this seems to have solved the issue.